# iOS/Web Payment options for small amount

Tags: ios, payment

What are my options for iOS/Web payment for small amounts 10cents up to $5 ?

Currently developing an iOS app that let users perform a service for another user
for low fees from $0.10 up to say $5 .

Just realized there is really no **really cheap** way of doing peer-to-peer transfer of that low amounts.

Any way users can redeem $0.10 as iTunes credit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out PayPal personal payment fits my use cases,
No fee at all when using bank account as funding source to transfer to another bank account (within the same country)

Comment: FYI:I don't have any promotional relationship with any of them, and I use various processors for different purposes... Be aware that if the _recipient_ has a non-personal account, there will be fees charged, depending on the payment source (that is, if credit/debit cards are used).

Comment: OK thanks for pointing this out Brad. There will need to be some check to notify users within the iOS app that the recipient has a non-personal accout.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Dwolla: https://www.dwolla.com

"No percentages. No hidden fees. Just 25¢ per transaction or free for transactions $10 or less." (From their page today, 10-Mar-2015)